# sense-emu no emulator detected and close_fds not supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run sense-emu on my windows machine but I have multiple errors.

What did I do? I installed the sense-emu python module

Which errors do I get?

```
E:\VS\SHARED\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\sense_emu\sense_hat.py:91: 
Warning: No emulator detected; spawning sense_emu_gui
warnings.warn(Warning('No emulator detected; spawning sense_emu_gui'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/PyCharmProjects/projet-3/main.py", line 5, in <module>
s = SenseHat()
File "E:\VS\SHARED\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\sense_emu\sense_hat.py", 
line 102, in __init__
close_fds=True)
 File "E:\VS\SHARED\Python36_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 624, in __init__
"close_fds is not supported on Windows platforms"
ValueError: close_fds is not supported on Windows platforms if you redirect 
stdin/stdout/stderr
```

I am using python 3.6

Comment: you can see the error: "close_fds is not supported on Windows platforms"

Comment: Dear lord what a genius, I couldn't read it for sure... How do I fix it smart boy

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/27220) too dude :)